# Twilio Rooms API not working as expected

Tags: javascript, ember.js, twilio, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm building a video conference application, previously which was using Twilio conversation API. As per recent [updates](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video) from Twilio,I tried the Rooms API with help of [twilio's quick start app](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/video-quickstart-ruby). I faced problem in fetching and attaching the remote participants media tracks. Here with I have attached the code sample, the Twilio library I'm using and ruby code for generating tokens.

Note: I use Ember JS for front end and ROR for back end.

### JavaScript code:

```
var twilioVideo = Twilio.Video;
Ember.debug('Initiaizing Video Client for ' + data.identity);
var twilioClient = new twilioVideo.Client(data.video_token);
Ember.debug('Initiaizing LocalMedia for ' + data.identity);
var localMedia = new twilioVideo.LocalMedia();
twilioVideo.getUserMedia().then(function(mediaStream){
  localMedia.addStream(mediaStream);
  localMedia.attach('#video-local');
  twilioClient.connect({to: 'randomRoomname'}). then(function(activeRoom){
    Ember.debug('Connected to the Room: ' + activeRoom.name);
    activeRoom.participants.forEach(function(participant) {
      participant.media.attach('div#remote-media');
      Ember.debug("Already in activeRoom: '" + participant.identity + "'");
    });
    activeRoom.once('participantConnected', function(participant){
      participant.media.attach('div#remote-media');
      Ember.debug('Participant '+participant.identity+' is connected');
    });
    activeRoom.once('participantDisconnected', function(participant){
      Ember.debug('Participant '+participant.identity+' is disconnected');
    });
  }, function(error) {
    Ember.debug('Failed to connect to room as ' + error);
  });
});
```

Twilio Video library taken from this [CDN](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0-beta2/twilio-video.js).

### Ruby code:

```
video_token = Twilio::Util::AccessToken.new(ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'], ENV['TWILIO_API_KEY'], ENV['TWILIO_API_SECRET'], 3600, identity)}

grant = Twilio::Util::AccessToken::VideoGrant.new
grant.configuration_profile_sid = ENV['TWILIO_CONFIGURATION_SID']
video_token.add_grant grant

json :identity => identity, :video_token => video_token.to_jwt
```

Twilio-ruby gem used: version 4.13.0.

PS: I use action cable to share messages between participants for some other features as my requirements.

Am I missing any other configurations or Do I need to enable anything from twilio side? I'm using this [tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

Without logs, I cannot be sure what is going wrong; however, I do see some improvements you could make.

1. You create LocalMedia and add a MediaStream to it, but you never use it. Instead, I think you should pass it into your `connect` call, e.g.

   ```
   twilioClient.connect({to: 'randomRoomname', localMedia: localMedia}).then(function(activeRoom) {
   ```
2. You should probably pass `audio: true` and `video: true` to the `getUserMedia` call, e.g.

   ```
   twilioVideo.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true }).then(function(mediaStream){
   ```
3. On the last line, I think you should handle the error case if `getUserMedia` fails, e.g.

   ```
   twilioVideo.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true }).then(function(mediaStream){
     // ...
   }, function(error) {
     console.error('getUserMedia failed:' + error);
   });
   ```
4. You may also wish to enable debug logging, e.g.

   ```
   var twilioClient = new twilioVideo.Client(data.video_token, { logLevel: 'debug' });
   ```

Can you retry after making these changes?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried improving my code with your suggestions. But still didn't help me. Here with I attach my twilio configuration [logs](http://pastebin.com/raw/zS0mnHFa). Also while going through logs, I found [tracks](http://pastebin.com/raw/sttEY0hi) are being send through wss messages. This is blocking me to enhance this module of the application. :(